# Adding new data types to Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to add a new LiquibaseDatatype extension and it is not being picked up by the ServiceLocator even though the JAR is in the 'lib' directory when running and is on the classpath.

I have added a static initialiser to log when the class is loaded (and to other methods) but still no joy.

```
public class MyType extends LiquibaseDataType {

static {
    System.out.println("LOADED");
}

public MyType() {
    System.out.println("CONSTRUCTED");
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    String result = "mytype";
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String[] getAliases() {
    return new String[] { "MYTYPE", };
}

@Override
public int getPriority() {
    return super.getPriority() + 10;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Database database) {
    boolean result = (database instanceof MySQLDatabase) || (database instanceof OracleDatabase)
            || (database instanceof DB2Database);
    return result;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode() + 37;
}
```

}

I know I could add database type property elements to the XML and use $ notation to do this..

```
<property name="MYTYPE" value="WHATEVER" dbms="db2"/>
<property name="MYTYPE" value="WHATEVER_ELSE" dbms="oracle"/>
...
<column name="COLX" type="${MYTYPE}"/>
...
```

but I'd like to have the type set explicitly.

```
<column name="COLX" type="mytype"/>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.